# Is xy pseudo-concave function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I know that $f(x,y) = xy$ is a quasi concave function on $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}$. However, I don't manage to se whether it is a pseudo-concave function or not... Could anyone please give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: If you happen to just not understand the rather obscure definition of "pseudo-concave", you should say so, because it might increase the probability of a useful answer.

Comment: Maybe an explanation would help a lot, yeah. Thanks!